# How does google know when im traveling to events?

Tags: privacy

Every time i head to punk rock shows i get reminders on my android phone of the event that i did not set how does it get this information do they do anything with it?

Comment: Do you get tickets mailed to a gmail account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s difficult to say for sure without more details about how you booked your concert tickets, but it is likely through email markup. Here’s some more info from a developer’s perspective:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/

This is the mechanism that powers “Google Now Cards”, allowing the email sender to provide some common parameters about transaction emails, like the date of an event, flight, or hotel stay.

Even without that though, it’s possible to attach calendar events to emails as an attachment.

Google also parses certain specific emails to provide a quick action link without actually opening the email (some password reset links, certain specific apps like Trello). I don’t think they take that as far as adding calendar events for you, though.